# Create field in a table (or query) for Network Days in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, field, datediff

I know Access does not support Network days directly. I also know I can use VBA to solve for the network days of any two values for one record on a form. However, I would like to solve network days for all records in a table. Example: need to find the percentage of records that were open/completed/whatever in less than a certain number of "work week days") To do this I need a column of how many network days each item took.

I have tried he following in query design to create new field.

Test:DateDiff([Initiated Date],[Closed Date],"d")-(((DateDiff([Initiated Date],[Closed Date],"d")+Weekday([Initiated Date],3)-Weekday([Closed Date],3))/7)*2)+1*(Weekday([Initiated Date],3)>5)-(Weekday([Closed Date],3)-4)*(Weekday([Closed Date],3)>4)

I have tried a few variations of this I have found online but this is the only one I have gotten to execute, but with #Error for all values.

**((Side Note: I entered this as one continuous line in the "Field" area of the query while in design view. kind of like how you can create a new field directly by using.... Newfieldname:[Field1]*[Field2] . I am only bringing this up as someone thought it was necessary to edit my post and move Test: to its own line....who knows maybe my use of Test:([extensive stuff]) was part of the problem!!!? Leave the original post alone if someone is literally stating "this is "stuff" that I "had" "somewhere"))**

The other option I have tried is to make a new field in VBA but have the fld.Expression refer to a function. (which I do not believe I can do or maybe not even doing correctly...)

Note: 'tblVBA is a temp table (I am not storing these calculated values.)

```
Private Sub btncreate_Click()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim TD As DAO.TableDef
    Dim fld As DAO.Field

    Set db = CurrentDb()
    Set TD = db.TableDefs("tblVBA") 

    Set fld = TD.CreateField("TotNetWrkDays", dbInteger)
    fld.Expression = wNetworkdays([Initiated Date], [Closed Date])
    TD.Fields.Append fld
    MsgBox "Added"
End Sub

Public Function wNetworkdays(beginDt As Date, endDt As Date) As Integer
    Dim tempDt As Date
    Dim count As Integer
    tempDt = beginDt

    For i = 1 To DateDiff("d", beginDt, endDt)
        tempDt = DateAdd("d", 1, tempDt)
        If Weekday(tempDt, 2) = 6 Or Weekday(tempDt, 2) = 7 Then  'Define your scheduled day off, you can define weekday instead of weekend
            count = count + 1
        End If
    Next i
    wNetworkdays = DateDiff("d", beginDt, endDt) + 1 - count
End Function
```

I can do all of this in excel sure...but, that would be unfortunate to only be able to find some simple stats outside of the db in excel.

---

---

Update: 11-2-2017 2:30PM 
Big Thanks to Kostas K. !!! I did not realize you could call a function from a query which essentially solved my issue. I did however use my original function as the provided solution...Example: between 3/17/2016 & 8/11/2016 produces a result of 105 as opposed to excels NETWORKDAYS which gives 106. the code I posted before (I found online btw) does give 106 like excel. 
*I will need to still add a return Null for all cases where Closed Date is not available.. but either way Question answered Thanks!

Comment: It's NETWORKDAYS or net work days, but "Network days" is rather confusing for your readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function below to find the number of weekdays (excluding weekends) between two dates.

Then you can simply call the function in your query.

```
Public Function WeekdaysInDateRange(ByVal DateFrom As Date, ByVal DateTo As Date) As Long
    Dim weeks As Long
        weeks = CLng((((DateTo - Weekday(DateTo)) - (DateFrom - Weekday(DateFrom) + 1)) / 7) * 5)

    Dim days As Long
        days = Weekday(DateTo) - Weekday(DateFrom) + 1 + IIf(Weekday(DateFrom) = 1, -1, 0) + IIf(Weekday(DateTo) = 7, -1, 0)

    WeekdaysInDateRange = weeks + days
End Function
```

Note `DateFrom` is not included in the calculation.